# Pass image as a binary representation

Tags: javascript, rest, request, binaryfiles, saga

I'm invoking an api that accepts image in the binary representation form. I'm uploading the image through a file upload html.

Here is my code:

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
  let fileData = fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(text.data.uploadedFile);
yield call(fetchJson, 'url/fetch', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Authentication: 'Basic <key>',
        'Content-type': 'image/jpeg'
      },
      body: fileData
    });
```

I get fileData as `undefined` and my request does not go through. This 3rd party API accepts image in binary representation form in the body.

This is equivalent to the following in POSTMAN:

[image]

This works in POSTMAN but not sure how to achieve this using code.

I set uploadedFile on front-end using: `event.target.files[0]`

Comment: Filereader is asynchronous. But why bother with it? you can just send the blob? xhr and fetch both accept blob as body